# Concatenate a variable to an HTML tag

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show an arrow next to a variable only if this variable is not null. The variable in question is `flight.c_tof`.

```
render() {
    const items = this.state.flights.map((flight) =>
        <tr key={flight.uid}>
            <td>{flight.c_tof == null ? null : flight.c_tof + <span className="icon-arrow-right icon-small"></span>}</td>
        </tr>
    )

    return ...{items}...
}
```

This outputs something like: `LPPD[object Object]`

If I remove `flight.c_tof +`, then it shows that arrow as it should. How can I concatenate that variable?

Comment: What's in the variable? I mean, what are you expecting to show up there? It seems like this should be a bit more normalized so you're not depending on JS's fun automatic type conversions. Keep in mind that a JSX element is an object, not a string. If `flight.c_tof` is a string, you're going to get the object's default string rep appended to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your td to

```
     <td>{flight.c_tof === null ? null : <span>{flight.c_tof}  <span className="icon-arrow-right icon-small"> </span></span>}</td>
```

You can only output one element as the result of the conditional. So, when you remove the `flight.c_tof +` , the output is just the span with the icon and it shows up fine. But when you add the `flight.c_tof +` it is not a valid html element and shows up as a javascript object.

Edited after @DaveNewton's comment:
You can create a component like

```
const ArrowField=(props)=>{
  return (<div>
    {props.data}
    <span className="icon-arrow-right icon-small"></span>
  </div>);
}
```

and then use it like

```
<td>{flight.c_tof === null ? null : <ArrowField data={flight.c_tof} />}</td>
```

Comment: Better yet, extract this out and make it obvious what's happening, either via a function or a micro-component.